# Difference between training accuracy and calculating accuracy with class prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have trained my neural network with a dataset of 11200 images, and its validation accuracy was 96%. I saved my model and load its weights to the same neural network. I chose 738 images of my dataset in an array, and tried to predict the class of each of them with my model, and compare them with true labels, then again I calculated the accuracy percentage and it was 74%. what is the problem here? I guess its accuracy should be about 96% again.

```
prelist=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    prediction = model.predict_classes(x[i])
    prelist.append(prediction)
count = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if(y[i] == prelist[i]):
        count = count + 1
test_precision = (count/len(x))*100
print (test_precision)
```

when I use predict class on 11200 images that I used to train the neural network and compare its result with true labels and calculated accuracy again its accuracy is 91%. I am using AlexNet and a binary classification in this problem. Thanks.

---

P.S: I attached my model plots, I guess it is not overfitting, at the end, I attached an overfitted model plot.

[image: Loss Plot]
[image: Accuracy Plot]

And an overfitted Loss plot is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not be evaluating the accuracy score on images used during training.
Evaluating the model always boils down to splitting the available data into three sets: training, validation and test. You train on the training data and evaluate your model on the validation datato measure loss and optimize/fine tune the netowork configuration during training). Once your model is ready for prime time, you test it on the test data.

Once training is complete, you can evaluate the accuracy on test set. 
If it still comes out to be ~70% while your training accuracy was ~90%, most likely the model has result in overfitting to the validation set. To counter that you can resort to techniques like

- Get more training data
- Add weight regularization
- Add droput
- Reduce the capacity of network

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and is it necessary to choose separate train/validation and test sets? how can I split them?

Comment: Once all images are loaded, create separate arrays for train_data and test_data, usually you can split as per 80:20 rule, i.e. 0.8 * 11200 = 8960 can be the training set, while 0.2 * 11200 = 2240 can be the test data. So you'll have to maintain four arrays train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label. And within train_data, validation  data will get split internally

Comment: I have checked my model accuracy and loss plots, I read when accuracy loss and validation loss curves starting to separate, that is overfitting. but my curves don't separate, I attached the images in question, check it, please.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig in "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach"

> ... you still want to measure performance on unseen data as a way of
>   selecting a good hypothesis, then divide the available data ... into a
>   training set and a validation set.

- **Train Data:** You always train the model on the train data. The model has access to true labels and there are chances that the model over fits to the train data and has high train accuracy.
- **Validation Data:** If you want to access how good the model is then evaluate the model on unseen data. This data is normally called validation data because you adjust the hype parameters during the train time so as to get the better validation accuracy. This may also lead to over fitting (via hyper parameters) over validation data.
- **Test Data:** You can do final measure of the model using the test data and publish these results as the model performance.

During training, you normally plot the train and validation loss (or accuracy) at each epoch the stop the training when validation loss is increasing but the train loss is decreasing.

You are clearly over fitting see the plot below

[image]

**What to do if the data is to small to be split to train-validation-test ?** : Use k-fold cross validation strategy.